# Sparse Fourier Transform for Sparse Pulse Trains

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, embedded-systems, sparse-model, sparse-fourier-transform

So I have signals for the form:

$$x_{k}(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{k,n} \cdot \delta(t - nT_k)$$

that I receive as a superposition:

$$x(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{K} \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{k,n} \cdot \delta(t - nT_k)$$

We know that (if we let $N \rightarrow \infty$) the Fourier transforms of the $x_k(t)$ are sparse, and therefore so would that of $x(t)$. In my application, my $N$ is fairly large so I say this holds rather well.

---

**Question:**

I want to compute a discrete Fourier transform that encourages the result to be as sparse as possible.

Can I use the sparse Fourier transform algorithm to compute the FFT of these signals? Will it produce a spectrum that is sparse in this case?

The sparse Fourier transform seems to rely on the OFDM trick, and, since the majority of my samples are zero, this isn't going to work. Should I just use a L1 regularization technique like the LASSO instead? Or should I just add a bit of noise to the signals to prevent the catastrophic numerical errors?

Thanks!

---

**Clarification:**

Note that I really just want an 'clean' FFT because I'm doing all of this on a computer. Even though I am constrained to set a fixed length for my FFT, the FFT of these signals, after the proper resampling, gives me an approximate pulse train contaminated with noise. An NUFFT gives me something similar. I want to know if I can reduce this noise using regularization or the sparse Fourier transform algorithm.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What do you make of this then? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593800/fourier-transform-of-pulse-train

Comment: ah sorry, I had a dumb-brain moment there for a second; a pulse *train* has a discrete Fourier transform, of course. A single pulse doesn't. Let me delete my bad comment.

Comment: But: you need to be *very* clear about what kind of Fourier transform you want: your question is about the FFT (which is just a DFT), and the formula above for $x_k$ is about time-continuous signals with infinite duration, which you *cannot* DFT, because, well, they are infinite and their sum is *only* periodic (and that period would be the minimal possible DFT length) if all $T_k$ are rationally related.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay. I will clarify. I really just want an FFT because I'm doing all of this on a computer. I have to set a fixed length for my FFT, yet, the FFT of these signals, after the proper resampling (and also an NUFFT), gives me an approximate pulse train contaminated with noise. I want to know if I can reduce this noise using regularization.

Comment: slightly confused by the statement "I want an FFT": it simply might not be applicable. So, is your original signal already time-discrete, or is it not? And if discrete, are $T_k$ all integers?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The signals are digitized, but the arrival times are random. I have a resampling procedure that optimally maps the pulses onto a uniform grid. Alternatively, I sometimes use a NUFFT when I can't resample. What I want is an algorithm that can take either type of input and produce a sparse spectrum. If it can do only one, that is fine too.

Comment: I'm more confused now: a digitizer wouldn't see a dirac as dirac, as that has infinite bandwidth. So, how do the pulses look *after* the analog anti-aliasing filter that *any* digitizer must have? (If you think yours got none, then the digitizer would have 0 probability of ever observing such a pulse – the pulse time and samping time would have to be *exactly* identical, and that, stochastically, certainly never happens.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Bro its a model. I can't reveal everything because of important reasons. The question stands as such. I've tried the LASSO algorithm and it works decently -- it improve things for sure. Now I am wondering if there is anything else.

Comment: Please don't call me "Bro". And if you cannot give us a coherent system description, we cannot help you. Not for "important" reasons, but because what you describe is paradoxical.